# Solace Provision Flag Set

Tags: c#, .net, solace

I am trying to provision a queue in solace as in [here](https://github.com/SolaceSamples/solace-samples-dotnet/blob/master/src/TopicToQueueMapping/TopicToQueueMapping.cs) by using

```
// Provision it, and do not fail if it already exists
session.Provision(queue, endpointProps,
ProvisionFlag.IgnoreErrorIfEndpointAlreadyExists & ProvisionFlag.WaitForConfirm, null);
Console.WriteLine("Queue '{0}' has been created and provisioned.", queueName);
```

However even though I set the flag to ProvisionFlag.WaitForConfirm as in the sample I am still getting ReturnCode In_Progress which means provision is not blocking as expected and also provision error that queue alread exist. any reason why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the documentation for Solace on Github is wrong. Instead of using the & operator it should be |.

Updated that to use | like

```
// Provision it, and do not fail if it already exists
session.Provision(queue, endpointProps,
ProvisionFlag.IgnoreErrorIfEndpointAlreadyExists | ProvisionFlag.WaitForConfirm, null);
Console.WriteLine("Queue '{0}' has been created and provisioned.", queueName);
```

And it works.

Comment: Yes, the github sample is incorrect. You need an OR operator to combine the bits of those two flags. I've submitted a pull request on your behalf (https://github.com/SolaceSamples/solace-samples-dotnet/pull/9)